# Is there any API for planes with ICAO identifiers?

Tags: icao, website

I'm looking for an API that I can use for images and details of all planes, preferably searched by the name of the plane or the ICAO identifier of the plane.

Right now, I've found a [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_type_designators) with every single aircraft ICAO identifier.

Furthermore, I've found a [website with most planes by ICAO](https://aviation-safety.net/graphics/ICAOtype/C25C.gif), but some things, for example the [**(S65C)** Eurocopter AS365 Dauphin](https://www.aviationfanatic.com/ent_show.php?ent=4&AT_ID=S65C) aren't included. That's the thing, it's not meant to be an API, just a collection of images.

Even with those, I can't run an API search for the name and stats for the plane.

Anything can work for me, if I have to, I can use multiple services, but all I really care for are:

- Plane stats
- Aircraft name
- ICAO identifier
- Image of plane

And those all have to be searched for by the ICAO and the aircraft model.

Also, I don't want completely paid APIs. I'm fine with keys that have a limited amount of calls in a certain period of time, but nothing that you have to pay for.

###### NOTE: I'm not looking for ICAO airport identifiers, that's an entirely different thing.

Comment: ICAO DOC8643 API is available here: https://www.icao.int/Aviation-API-Data-Service/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: Adding the @60levelchange link info, the [structure of the queries and the responses](https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Documents/API-Catalogue-v01.pdf).

Comment: @60levelchange Oh, yes, nice resource, but I forgot to mention that I don't want paid APIs. I will edit my post.

Comment: Also, @60levelchange, do you know how to get an ICAO api key? I saw very expensive (talking about like $20K) api calls, but I didn't find out how to get a key.

Comment: Once again, @60levelchange, I searched up "doc8643" which is a document (that you can buy) that has all the identifiers. I came across this [free doc8643 website here](https://doc8643.com/aircrafts), but it doesn't seem like I can access it in any way, other than web scraping which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: You're not going to find DOC8643 for free anywhere (at least not an up-to-date version). ICAO charges big bucks for their documents, unfortunately

Comment: @60levelchange LOL, that's so ironic, because I just did. While searching on NPM, I found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aircraft-recognizer?activeTab=code). (To view it, click on "resources")

Comment: Oh, I guess it's not up to date.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are looking for aircraft **types** rather than the planes themselves, right? Also exactly what details are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to make an API that **searches for the plane using ICAO identifier** and then **returns images, stats,** and most importantly **aircraft name**

Comment: Not sure what's "ironic" about it. That link is to a 4-year old version of DOC8643. As I said, you very likely won't find an up-to-date version for free.